# Opencart retriving data from 3 tables

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

Hello I have this query:

```
    $sql = "SELECT email_id as name,competition_rate as rate, competition.competition_id, competition.end_date 
FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "competition_winners as competition_winners, 
     ". DB_PREFIX . "competition as competition,
    ". DB_PREFIX . "customer as customer

WHERE competition.competition_id = competition_winners.competition_id and customer.email=competition_winners.email_id";
```

What I need is to retrive an other row called comptition_rate from table costumer. I am using opencart and it would be greate to display it in a same row as customer email it displayed as a name. Is it posible at all and how it could be dome?

P.s. Changed code a little but I cannot display all results only competition_rate or email.

Comment: I've got 2 tables A and B. I need to get the name field from table C. I'm using opencart. Please help me.  --- Your question appears like this. We need the details about all
 tables.

Comment: Sorry if I scrood up you and others. Acually I have 3 tables I just have to select data from table c or customers field based on parameter email from table competition_winners

Comment: Have You ever heard of `JOIN`? Your query and DB structure are incorrect. You should be using `JOIN`s and instead of using `email = email_id` as a unique key for comparison You should be using primary keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  $sql = "SELECT email_id as name,customer.comptition_rate as newcomrate,competition_rate as rate, competition.competition_id, competition.end_date 
FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "competition_winners as competition_winners, 
     ". DB_PREFIX . "competition as competition,
    ". DB_PREFIX . "customer as customer WHERE competition.competition_id = competition_winners.competition_id and customer.email=competition_winners.email_id";
```

try with this query and you will get your data on this `newcomrate` field

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $sql = "SELECT email_id as name,customer.comptition_rate as rate, competition.competition_id, competition.end_date  FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "competition_winners as competition_winners, ". DB_PREFIX . "competition as competition, ". DB_PREFIX . "customer as customer WHERE competition.competition_id = competition_winners.competition_id and customer.email=competition_winners.email_id";
```

Have a nice day!!

Comment: Thank you very much Guys!!! It works. Only thin I did, I added rate index to view and controller files.